# bootstrap multi item carousel works on bootply but not on browser

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, bootply

Hi I'm trying to make a multi item bootstrap carousel that slide one item at a time. exactly what this bootply is doing. http://www.bootply.com/94452
when I copy paste the code in an editor and of course link jquery and bootstrap cdn, the carousel doesn't slide item by item.

Any idea why? 
This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide row" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
```

JS:

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    next=next.next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }

    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

the code is the same as shown in Bootply except the bootstrap and jquery cdn and stylesheet link in the html.

why does it only work on Bootply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out how to enable the carousel to slide one item at a time on a normal browser.

1) From the html file, remove "slide" from , so it is just . This will prevent bootstrap's default carousel slide

2) Include animate.css from https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">` This will give you many cool animation effects to customize your carousel.
3) In the css file add:

```
.item {
  animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

4) In the animate.css file, change transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) to 25%

you can select any animation effect you want form animate.css!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script> -->
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel row" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }
.carousel-control.right { right: -50px; }
.carousel-control.left { left: -50px; }
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.item {
  animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));


    for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
      next=next.next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

animate.css:

Change existing code to:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideInRight {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(25%, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

.slideInRight {
  -webkit-animation-name: slideInRight;
  animation-name: slideInRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's something wrong with that BootstrapJS CDN. I'm seeing this error in Chrome:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'A783Hjykc5z+a+ph8BJrfLuU5HE+lwZR+azVrLPZ45k='. The resource has been blocked.

And therefore it doesn't know what $(...).carousel is in test.js. Try the latest version of Bootstrap from the CDN:

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work with updated bootstrap cdn. I don't get any javascript errors like that on my end. It works, but the carousel just doesn't slide one by one like how it does on bootply. I just don't understand why the same code will work on bootply and not on regular browser.